# Use result of Mutation in another Mutation

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I want to create a Form hook that calls multiple mutations before using the result of all these mutations as input for one final mutation:

```
const NewWarriorForm = (props) => {
    const [ createWeapon,{ loading, error, data} ] = useMutation(CREATE_WEAPON);
    const [ createArmor,{ loading, error, data} ] = useMutation(CREATE_ARMOR);
    const [ createWarrior,{ loading, error, data} ] = useMutation(CREATE_WARRIOR);

    const handleSubmission = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let target = e.target
        let weapon_id = submitNewWeapon(target, createWeapon)
        let armor_id = submitNewArmor(target, createArmor);
        submitNewWarrior(target, createWarrior, weapon_id, armor_id);
        toggle();
    }

    return (
        <Form id={formId} onSubmit={handleSubmission} >
           ...
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Where `submitNewWeapon` would look like this:

```
function submitNewWeapon(target, createWeapon) {
    const weapon = target["weapon"].value;

    createWeapon({ variables: {
        weapon: weapon
    }})
}
```

And `CREATE_WEAPON` would be:

```
const CREATE_WEAPON = gql`
mutation CreateWeapon(
    $weapon: String!
) {
    createWeapon(
      weapon: $weapon
    ) {
        ok
        weapon {
            weaponId
        }
     }
}
`;
```

The issue I get is that `weapon_id` and `armor_id` always come back as `undefined`. Can anyone provide me with the best approach?